# libunwind-arm.so: undefined reference to `__builtin_unreachable'

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I got this error compiling libunwind-1.1.so for arm926. This is the launched command:

```
sb2 ./configure --prefix=/usr --target=armv5;sb2 make all
```

This is the output:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -fexceptions -Wall -Wsign-compare   -o Gperf-simple Gperf-simple.o ../src/libunwind-arm.la ../src/libunwind.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -fexceptions -Wall -Wsign-compare -o .libs/Gperf-simple Gperf-simple.o  ../src/.libs/libunwind-arm.so ../src/.libs/libunwind.so
../src/.libs/libunwind-arm.so: undefined reference to `__builtin_unreachable'
../src/.libs/libunwind-arm.so: undefined reference to `_Uarm_get_elf_image'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that part of your problem is that you're using an old version of gcc. See [Emulating GCC's __builtin_unreachable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031819/emulating-gccs-builtin-unreachable)

The other thing to note is that you've already built libunwind.so. What's failing is a program (Gperf-simple) being built after the library build.

I compile and use libunwind for arm as part of my [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) cross compiler toolkit project, in part to support C++ exceptions and stack unwinding. What are you using libunwind for?

Comment: I need to compile libunwind to get a working gperf-tools version for arm: https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/issues/detail?id=572#c7

Comment: As I have to fix also `_Uarm_get_elf_image' error, I think I'll migrate to gprof... However, thank you Richard.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the "undefined reference to `_Uarm_get_elf_image'" issue.

I worked around it by editing libunwind src/Makefile.am, making the "if OS_LINUX" section unconditional and deleting all the other "if OS_*" sections.

This got it building for me, YMMV.