# Emulating GCC's __builtin_unreachable in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6031819/10147399) question which is about emulating `__builtin_unreachable` in an older version of GCC. My question is exactly that, but for Visual Studio (2019). Does Visual Studio have some equivalent of `__builtin_unreachable`? Is it possible to emulate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC has the [`__assume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/assume?view=vs-2019) builtin which can be used to implement `__builtin_unreachable`. As the documentation says, `__assume(0)` must not be in a reachable branch of code, which means, that branch must be unreachable.

Answer (score 7):

By the way, before [std::unreachable()](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0627r3.pdf) is available you can implement it as a compiler-independent function, so that you don't have to define any macros:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ // GCC 4.8+, Clang, Intel and other compilers compatible with GCC (-std=c++0x or above)
[[noreturn]] inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void unreachable() {__builtin_unreachable();}
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) // MSVC
[[noreturn]] __forceinline void unreachable() {__assume(false);}
#else // ???
inline void unreachable() {}
#endif
```

Usage:

```
int& g()
{
    unreachable();
    //no warning about a missing return statement
}

int foo();

int main()
{
    int a = g();
    foo(); //any compiler eliminates this call with -O1 so that there is no linker error about an undefined reference
    return a+5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has [`__assume(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/assume?view=vs-2019) for this use-case.

Comment: It would be nice if this were standardized. Something like `[[unreachable]]`.

Comment: @Ayxan The proposal working through is actually a function: [`std::unreachable()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0627r3.pdf). Probably for C++23.

Answer (score 1):

C++23 will have [std::unreachable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) as a cross-platform alternative.